# Как пользователь делает двойной запрос?

Tags: php

Ребят, приветствую.
На сайте есть функция вывода средств. Потом обнаружил, что один пользователь каким-то образом пополнял 1 раз, а выводил эти же средства по 2 раза.(именно по 2, ни больше ни меньше).
Вот у меня и возник вопрос, как он смог это сделать, если у меня идет сначала списание с баланса, а потом сам вывод(в случае ошибки вывода возвращаю на баланс).
У меня есть мысль, но не уверен в её правильности. Если я например вставлю функцию sleep с рандомным числом от 0 до 1, поможет ли это устранить эту проблему? Или это решается как-то по другому?

```
if ( $_POST['amount'] <= $balance ) {
    $payeer = new CPayeer($accountNumber, $apiId, $apiKey);
    if ($payeer->isAuth()) {

        $bal_ret = $balance;
        $balance_res = $balance - $_POST['amount'];
        mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `users`  SET `balance` = $balance_res WHERE `id` = '$us_id'");

        $wallet_send = $_POST['payeer'];
        $arTransfer = $payeer->transfer(array('curIn' => $m_curr,'sum' => $_POST['amount'],'curOut' => $m_curr,'to' => $wallet_send,'comment' => 'Вывод средств',));

        if (empty($arTransfer['errors'])) {
            MessageSend(2, 'Средства успешно выведены', '/cashout');
        } else {
            mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `users`  SET `balance` = $bal_ret WHERE `id` = '$us_id'");
            MessageSend(1, 'Средства не удалось вывести. Пожалуйста, попробуйте позже.', '/cashout');
        }


    } else {
        MessageSend(1, 'Что-то пошло не так.', '/cashout');
    }
} else {
    MessageSend(1, 'Недостаточно средств', '/cashout');
}
```

Comment: Покажите, как у вас расчитывается `$balance`?

Comment: Это решается атомарностью операции "получить баланс-сравнить-списать"

Comment: Почему не привели код открытия-закрытия транзакций?

Comment: А так-то да, операции "проверить текущий баланс" и "списать, если средств достаточно" должны проходить в рамках однйо транзакции

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

Comment: Много денег удалось украсть злоумышленнику?

Comment: @rjhdby и в этой ситуации не сработает даже если будут 2 подготовленных запроса будут использованы в одну долю секунды?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan нет, меньше 10к руб.

Comment: @rjhdby балансе просто берется из базы, из таблицы с пользователями. Не рассчитывается.

Comment: @ДанилСысоев нет, не помогут, только транзакция

Comment: Да, две параллельные транзакции с одной строкой в базе не получится закоммитить. У всех кроме одной будет ошибка с `concurrency update`

Comment: Замените UPDATE на что то в этом роде: `UPDATE users  SET balance = balance-$ammount WHERE id = $us_id and balance-$ammount >= 0` т.е. что бы запрос сам смотрел текущий баланс в БД, не доверяя вычислениям, выполненным в PHP не одномоментно. После этого смотрите количество обновленных записей (`mysqli_affected_rows()`), что бы понять, произошло ли изменение и если произошло пробуйте выполнить transfer. деньги в случае ошибки возвращайте подобным же запросом. Правда остается момент, что transfer даст сбой, а скрипт упадет и не успеет вернуть деньги на счет

Comment: только не забудьте предварительно убедиться, что $ammount число и оно положительно. Что бы не нашлись желающие пополнять свой счет, заказывая вывод отрицательных сумм. И раз уж используете mysqli то не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса, используйте привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  В текущем варианте возможны SQL-инъекции, которые в простых приложениях очень плохо, а в связанных с деньгами - катастрофичны

Comment: @Mike, с текущим кодом могли сначала снять отрицательную сумму, зачислив себе деньги, а потом два раза положительную.

Comment: @Mike премного благодарен за разъяснение. Будем копать в эту сторону. Спасибо большое.