# Как пользователь выводит средства дважды?

Tags: php

Ребят, приветствую. На сайте есть функция вывода средств. Потом обнаружил, что один пользователь каким-то образом пополнял 1 раз, а выводил эти же средства по 2 раза.(именно по 2, ни больше ни меньше). Вот у меня и возник вопрос, как он смог это сделать?
В [соседнем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747102/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) подсказали решить эту задачу через транзакции, однако не помогло. Пользователь все-равно таким же образом выводит средства.

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();

$stmt_cashout = "update users set balance = :balance where id = :id";
$stmt_us = "select * from users where id = :id";

$user_info = $pdo->prepare($stmt_us);
$user_exec = $user_info->execute([':id' => $us_id]);
$user_fetch = $user_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$_POST['amount'] = (int)$_POST['amount'];
$balance = (int)$user_fetch['balance'];

if ( isset($_POST['cashout']) ) {
    if ( $_POST['amount'] >= 10 ) {
        if ( $_POST['amount'] <= $balance ) {
            $payeer = new CPayeer($accountNumber, $apiId, $apiKey);
            if ($payeer->isAuth()) {

                $balance_res = $balance - $_POST['amount'];
                $res = $pdo->prepare($stmt_cashout);
                $res->execute(['balance' => $balance_res, 'id' => $us_id]);

                $wallet_send = $_POST['payeer'];
                $arTransfer = $payeer->transfer(array('curIn' => $m_curr,'sum' => $_POST['amount'],'curOut' => $m_curr,'to' => $wallet_send,'comment' => 'Вывод из проекта '.$dom.'.mlmone.click'.' ['.id_in_login($us_id).']',));

                if (empty($arTransfer['errors'])) {
                    $pdo->commit();
                    MessageSend(2, 'Средства успешно выведены', '/cashout');
                } else {
                    $pdo->rollBack();
                    MessageSend(1, 'Средства не удалось вывести. Пожалуйста, попробуйте позже.', '/cashout');
                }


            } else {
                MessageSend(1, 'Что-то пошло не так.', '/cashout');
            }
        } else {
            MessageSend(1, 'Недостаточно средств', '/cashout');
        }
    } else {    
        MessageSend(1, 'Минимальная сумма 10<i class=\"fa fa-$cur_ech\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>.', '/cashout');
    }
}
```

Comment: Запрос баланса ТАКЖЕ должен быть внутри транзакции. Вам же писали об этом

Comment: Ваша beginTransaction скорее всего ничего не даст. потому что запись надо блокировать до того как баланс прочитан. А у вас сначала читается баланс, потом открывается транзакция, между этими двумя событиями запросто другой скрипт может прочитать баланс, потом подождать пока первый завершит действия, а потом произвести свои, но баланс то у вас уже в переменной в php и он старый ... И я вам в том вопросе писал как правильно написать update что бы исключить такие ситуации и тот update практически единственно верный путь

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Исправил с учетом Вашего комментария. Скажите, правильно ли я Вас понял?

Comment: Начало транзакции само по себе ничего дает, запись все равно надо явно блокировать, например к select из users добавить в конце `for update`.

Comment: правда теперь у вас куча причин что бы транзакция так и осталась висеть не завершенной. например если не сработает любой из 4х if вы вообще не попадете в блок где происходит commit/rollback. так что я бы предложил еще в самом конце после последней закрывающейся скобки сделать явно rollback

Comment: И кстати, я надеюсь у вас таблица InnoDB, потому как MyISAM трензакции не поддерживает в принципе

Comment: @Mike да, rollback я уже добавил. Только пришлось добавить в конец всех if, так как функция MessageSend прекращает скрипт и переносит на другую страницу.

Comment: В общем если `for update` добавили, то начинает выглядеть идеально, вроде все предусмотрели. Другой, параллельно работающий скрипт остановится в момент `for update` и будет ждать пока завершится тот что уже взял блокировку. А значит гарантированно прочитает уже измененный баланс

Comment: @Mike да, innoDB

Comment: @Mike for update, тоже посмотрел как работает и добавил в конец подготовленного запроса. Будем смотреть дальше.  Средств оставил немного на балансе на всякий случай, чтобы не жалко было. Спасибо Вам за наводки, и за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд типичная гонка. Формирует 2 запроса так чтоб второй выполнил $payeer->transfer() до того как закончится первый вызов.

Чтоб предотвратить это безобразие нужно установить блокировку строк в базе данных.

Также возможен вариант что перед первой транзакцией резервировать сумму на счету каким-то быстрым запросом, а потом переводить.

В одном билинге было устроенно так что сначала выполнялся селект на возможность использования карточки, а потом делался вывод без проверки.
Там я добавил проверку использована ли карточка в запрос вывода.